# Unix (osx) command line image processor?

Tags: macos, command-line

I have a jpeg image of 400x400 px that i want to paste into a 960x640 image.
Is there a command line image processor that I can use on OSX?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're on OS X, you can look into [SIPS](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html) (scriptable image processing system) since it is installed by default.  I'm not sure I fully understand what you're doing, but from your comments it looks like you're just trying to resize the image.  If that's the case, have a look at the `--resampleHeightWidth`, `--padToHeightWidth`, and  `--cropToHeightWidth` options on the man page linked above.

For example, you might try `sips -z 960 640 yourinputimage.jpeg`

**EDIT:**  Based on your comment -- no, you cannot do this with SIPS to my knowledge.  As others have mentioned, your best bet is probably ImageMagick.  Once installed, you can use the `composite` command-line tool to do what you're asking.  See [this documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/composite.php).

Comment: Thank you! No, not really resize. I want to "paste" the 400x400 image on y 960x640 canvas. I want to keep the proportions of the original image. is that possible?

Comment: @tzippy: Ah, I understand.  You can't do this with SIPS -- you'll need to use ImageMagick as others have suggested.  See my edited answer.

Comment: `sips -p 960 640 filename.jpg` will center the original image in a 960x640 canvas -- is this what you need?

Comment: Thanks Gordon! Exactly what I needed.
I use  --padColor to get a white canvas!
sips -p 960 640  --padColor FFFFFF original.jpg

Answer (score 4):

If you want it on iPhone, then I'll suggest you to search or even [build Image Magick for the iPhone](http://www.cloudgoessocial.net/2009/06/09/imagemagick-on-iphone-with-jpeg-png/).

It will allow you to resize images right from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

There are command-line tools like [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx), but you might find OSX's Automator to be easier to use.

Comment: my goal is, to use it on the iPhone afterwards.

Comment: Use the image on the iPhone, or run the image processing program on the iPhone?

Comment: no, use the image processor on the iphone. i use a shell script and curl to dl an image that i need to resize and then replace LockBaground.png with this image to make it my wallpaper.